# How can Google Analytics be incorporated in HTML5 Mobile App that has offline/online mode?

Tags: ios, html, jquery-mobile, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have an HTML5 Mobile App based on JQuery Mobile. It fetches nothing from the server, is sometimes connected to the internet but also has offline mode. Does Google Analytics support offline mode?  Note, I am not using the Android/iOS SDK.  Just ga.js inside JQueryMobile pages.  Thanks

Below is my html5 JQueryMobile code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Mobile @ Your Library</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js">  </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-40418-saddf']);

    _gaq.push(['_gat._anonymizeIp']);

    (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/u/ga_debug.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
     })();

</script>



</script>
<body>
```

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="d"> 
    <h1>Mobile @ Your Library</h1>
    <a href="#home" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="d" class="ui-btn-right">home</a>
</div><!-- /header --> 

<div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li><a href="#search">Search</a></li>
        <li><a href="#hours">Hours</a></li>
        <li><a href="#ask">Ask a Librarian</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#where" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop">Where</a></li>
    </ul>       

</div><!-- /content --> 

<div data-role="footer" data-id="myfooter" data-position="fixed" data-theme="d"> 
    <div class="controls" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <a href="#home" data-role="button" data-icon="home">Home</a>
        <a href="#search" data-role="button" data-icon="search">Search</a>
        <a href="#ask" data-role="button" data-icon="info">Ask</a>
        <a href="/index.php" rel="external" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">Full site</a>
    </div>
</div><!-- /footer -->  
</div><!-- /page -->
<!--
<script type="text/javascript">
$('[data-role=page]').live('pageshow', function (event, ui) {
    console.log('pageshow called s');
    console.log('pageshow called s2');
     try {
    _gaq.push( ['_trackPageview', event.target.id] );
    console.log('tracked '+event.target.id);
    } catch(err) {
       console.log('error '+ err);
    }

});
</script>-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).delegate('[data-role=page]', 'pageshow', function (event, ui) {
console.log('pageshow event '+ui.prevPage.id);
var url = location.href;
console.log('pageshow url = '+url);
try  {

    if (location.hash) {

        url = location.hash;
        console.log('location.hash so now url = '+url);
    }
    console.log('about to push page '+url);
    //_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', url]);
    _gaq.push( ['_trackPageview', event.target.id] );
    console.log('about to push page '+url);
} 
catch(error) {
    // error catch
    console.log('error '+error);
}
});

</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Is GA questions off limits on SO.  I'm not seeing any answers or even questions.

Comment: I guess the idea would be that you detect if no internet connection is present (e.g. [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9526647/check-if-connected-to-a-network-jquery), if its not you store the events you want to pass to GA in webdb or whichever storage medium. Upon the next initiation you check again, and if connection is present + there are events in the local queue, you fire them. Obviously your event timing is gonna be unusable so you would have to figure out what actions are worth storing.

Comment: GA questions are allowed, but there are a some people around here who don't understand that GA also involves javascript coding, so they close it or move the topic to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics instead - which is fair enough for the questions that are solely report-based.. but since a lot of GA questions are solely js based or a hybrid.. kinda gets on my nerves sometimes but oh well.  In any case, click on the `google-analytics` tag under your question..you will see lots of Q&A.

Answer (score 0):

The GA code has to be able to send a request to the server in order to track data.  If you are in offline mode and not making any requests, there will be no tracking.